# Is it possible to hide APIKEY and still run normal?

Tags: git

I have a project with API KEY
How can I upload it to Github and hide api key?
And of course if download the project it will still run normal.

Comment: Check out [git-secret](https://git-secret.io/)

Comment: Please be a bit more specific. Is it a backend project or a frontend project? See also this for a good overview on API keys security https://developers.google.com/maps/api-security-best-practices?authuser=0

Answer (score 1):

A common way to do that is using [environment variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#:%7E:text=An%20environment%20variable%20is%20a,in%20which%20a%20process%20runs.). And adding the path to the file containing them to the `.gitignore` file to avoid sending them to git